# 'Uknown block type` when decrypting using BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle

I have string encrypted with RSA using **private key** and I have to decrypt it using **public key**. The exception I get is `uknown block type`

My key is `pem` formatted of type

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
< weird string which is the key>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And my code is

```
string pubKey = File.ReadAllText(_filePath + @"\keys\key.pub");

try
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    var resBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strEnc);
    var decEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

    using (var txtreader = new StringReader(pubKey))
    {
        var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

        decEngine.Init(false, keyParameter);
    }

    var decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decEngine.ProcessBlock(resBytes, 0, resBytes.Length));
    return decrypted;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

`_filePath` is the project directory.

I can't find `BouncyCastle` documentation and can't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You got it backwards. You encrypt with **public** key and decrypt with **private** key

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know, but the customer will send encrypted string using private key.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I guess OP has this part in bold, because that is exactly what he needs.

Comment: @Evk Yes, I know. OP: read [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key) this is most likely impossible

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto A file-signature is essentially the hash of the data encrypted with the private key, so technically it's not impossible to encrypt the whole file with the private key. It's stupid but it's possible.